# I can get PHP code to unzip a file running on Linux, but not on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I am not entirely sure that this is coding problem, so I'll describe my Windows environment, just in case: system is windows 10 Pro x64 build 1809, I have XAMPP windows x64 7.2.18-0-VC15 installed. On XAMPP I have PHP Version 7.2.18.

Following PHP code executes OK when I try it **on Linux** (took it from Stackoverflow)
:

```
function unzip_db($filename) {  
    $zip = new ZipArchive;  
    $res = $zip->open($filename);   
    if($res === TRUE)   {       
        $zip->extractTo('./');      
        $zip->close();      
        echo 'File is now uncompressed...';     
    }   else    {       
    echo "Can't open ".$filename;
    echo $res;
    }
}
```

When I try to run it **under Windows** this code always fails on the test **`if($res === TRUE)`** I am now not sure what to do: I  check the output of `phpinfo();` is says about ZIP: Zip enabled, Zip version: 1.15.4, Libzip version:    1.4.0, that could mean that I PHP have ZIP support and I am doing something wrong. I have also located and downloaded php_zip.dll (from [https://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.15.4/windows](https:////pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.15.4/windows)) and added line `extension=php_zip.dll`to php.ini file, but nothing has changed.
I ran out of ideas and I still don't know do I have a coding or environment config trouble, or what... 
Any suggestions?

Comment: if `$zip-open()` does not return `TRUE`, it returns an error code. You're echo'ing `$res`, what is its value?

Comment: check the path for $filename

Comment: @rickdenhaanv - I've checked `$res`, it has a value of 19. Unfortunately, I was already confused, so I didn't think of going to docs and checking what it means.

Comment: @ GabrieleMartini - I was 100% sure I have it right, but now- not so much until I check the code received in `$res` as suggested by @ rickdenhaan.

Comment: BTW: downloading  php_zip.dll and enabling it in php.ini was redundant. Info given by  phpinfo() was to be trusted! On the page [link]https://www.codexworld.com/extract-zip-gzip-rar-archive-file-using-php/[link] I found quick & easy way to check if unzip functionality  is supported in PHP.

Comment: Now I am really confused: code 19 means **not a Zip archive**. But I've zipped a test zip file under windows (using 7zip) and also uploaded it to Linux. So the **same file unzips** OK on Linux , bur fails to do so on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**We can close this question.** I have found that after I've zipped the test files and uploaded that to Linux, I downloaded them back to Windows box. It is that files creating the issue with PHP. It is kind of strange that I can still open them with 7zip, but I cant open them with Windows's built in unzipper. 
Even when I upload that files back to Linux,  I can still unzip them with PHP. Seems there is difference between Linux and Windows implementation of ZIPlibraries, **but that is not the reason for the problems**.
So I have to troubleshoot what happens when up/downloading the files - but that is out of scope of this question.
Thanks for your contribution. It helped to set me straight, so I was able to determine wherein lays the trouble.